# List.Remove always removes last item for ListView

Tags: android, listview

When i try to remove a specific item from a list View:

```
        buyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tempToken -= selPerk.cost;
            plrPerks.add(selPerk);
            String tokStr = String.valueOf(tempToken);
            tkn.setText(tokStr);
            shopItems.remove(selPerk);
            selPerk = new Perk();
            perkDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

It always seems to remove the last item. This is where i open the dialog:

```
perks.setClickable(true);
    perks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            Perk perk = (Perk) perks.getItemAtPosition(position);
            showItem(perk);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the show Item function:

```
public void showItem(Perk perk) {
    if (tempToken >= perk.cost) {
        selPerk = perk;
```

How do i remove a specific item from a list and list view respectively?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

In "setOnItemClickListener" listener, you are getting the perk object. So you can remove that object from your list like this-

```
shopItems.remove(perk);
```

and then you can call-

```
your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to refresh your listview.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a specific item from a list view, your can call removeView(View toBeRemoved) if you have a reference to the view you wish to remove.  If you have the index, you can call removeView(int index).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

You can remove a specific item from a list in the same way, using remove(Object item) or remove(int index).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: These methods are not supported anymore, see this-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#removeAllViews()

Comment: well i used the second one: Remove(Object) but thats not working

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Whenever i removed an item i had to do it like so:

```
shopItems.remove(selPerk);
perk_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So i had to notify my listeview adapter that i removed an item.